# Moving or Deleting an Outlook Message via the exchange EWS

Tags: jquery, api, soap, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Outlook add-in with office.js and trying to delete a message in a via the EWS API (soap envelopes). Following the docs DeleteItem Operation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/deleteitem-operation, unfortunately does not work for me. I'm making an mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync() request with the follwing request envelope. Also try moving to trash,
Request:

```
"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
xmlns:m=""https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages""
xmlns:t=""https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types""
xmlns:soap=""https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version=""Exchange2013""/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:MoveItem>
      <m:ToFolderId>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id=""deleteditems""/>
      </ m:ToFolderId>
      <m:ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id=""{0}""/>
      </m:ItemIds>
    </m:MoveItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to comment that when sending the request it returns The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1):

Currently,`mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync()` can only access a subset of EWS operations as listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions#readwritemailbox-permission). `DeleteItem` is not supported and will result in an error response. There are other ways to delete items like using `MoveItem`, please refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/deleting-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange#deleting-items---what-are-my-options) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I understand that operation deleteitem cannot be used, so please try moveitem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/moveitem-operation ? redirectedfrom = MSDN, and the SOAP example posted but it doesn't work either.
returns: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error